# Как подключить CSS из HTML документа?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Возможно ли ссылаться на элемент в HTML документе при подключении CSS во фрейме или окне, открытом через `window.open` (не копируя сам текст из `<style>`) ?

Comment: Возможно ли ссылаться на элемент в HTML документе? - Возможно, если элемент существует. А при чём тут CSS? Котлеты DOM отдельно, мухи CSS отдельно.

Comment: как же жаль...(